# Swing app.only shows one record in JTextArea

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtextarea

I'm working on an application that prints the results of an SQL query in a `JTextArea`. The database connection and query work and I can show the results in the console and in the text area, the only problem is, the text area only shows one record while the console shows all the results.

Here's my code to output the result set in the console and the text area. How can I modify the text area part to show all the values of the result set?

```
Statement stat = con.createStatement();           
ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT rnaam, gesl FROM dier, soort      WHERE soort.nsnaam = 'leeuw' ORDER BY rnaam ASC");

while(result.next())
{
    // The console print
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));

    // The frame print
    uitvoerText.setText(result.getString(1));
}
```

So what's the problem with my code, or, how can I simply display all the results? I know this is possible with a Model method (`ModelItem`), but I have to do it with a text area (school...). And I know I should use prepared statements, but we don't do that right now.

Comment: Only add the Netbeans tag if the question is about Netbeans.  This one obviously isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setText()` sets the text area to the given text, replacing whatever is already there.  What you want is `append()` which adds the given text to the end of the current.

```
uitvoerText.append(result.getString(1) + System.lineSeparator());
```

It's all in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

Comment: Which method will let me print all records? Because the exercise clearly says 'all rows in a JTextArea'.

Comment: `append()`, perhaps with a `"\n"` (or platform the independant `System.lineSeparator()`) at the end of your `String` to make sure each entry is on it's own line

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
 StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();
    while(result.next())
    {
        // The console print
        System.out.println(result.getString(1));
        //save it in stringBuilder
        text.append(result.getString(1)+System.lineSeparator());

    }
      uitvoerText.setText(text.toString());
```

Comment: Why do all of this an not just append to the `JTextArea`?

Comment: @RossDrew: JtextArea is also using the same kind of (not exact) logic internally in append API.

Comment: @RossDrew: In your case append gets call every time. So it creates StringBuilder object in heap every time(Due to looping). Whereas I am creating only one object in heap

Comment: @SachinPasalkar Really thats for the OP to decide. Regardless, some explanation as to why this is a good solution (or in fact what it does) in the answer itself would probably make this a good answer